# Getting rid of Yellow black lines in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Code:**

```
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: msg.snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  if (doc["uid"] == widget.user.uid) {
                    isme = true;
                  } else {
                    isme = false;
                  }
                  return Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: isme?MainAxisAlignment.end:MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                         
                        Column(
                        
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                color: isme ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,

                                ),
                              

                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text("${doc['msg']}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                                      Text("${doc['Name']}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.grey),),
                                      

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )),
                                
                          ],
                        ),
                      isme? Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.redAccent,):Text("")
                      ],
                    );
                });
          },
        ),
      ),
      //bottom textbar
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.user.photoURL))),
            SizedBox(width: 5),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: chatmsg,
                minLines: 1,
                maxLines: 4,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Send message...",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 5),
            Expanded(
                child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.send,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    sendmsg();
                    chatmsg.clear();
                  }),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            ))
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEl7Y.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wrap your `Column` widget with `Expanded` inside your `Row` widget.

```
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: isme?MainAxisAlignment.end:MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded( // <------ HERE
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              color: isme ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
            ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("${doc['msg']}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                Text("${doc['Name']}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.grey),),
                                  

                                ],
                              ),),
                            )),
                            
                      ],
                    ),
                  isme? Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.redAccent,):Text("")
                  ],
                );
            });
```

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks but can u explain why?

Comment: I'm told the error message when you get an overflow points you at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout . Even if it didn't, go read that.

Comment: The yellow & black lines show that your widget is getting overflowed. By using `Expanded` widget, you are specifying that your widget will fill to occupy the available space. If it gets overflowed, it will move the text to the next line.

Comment: Also, if you found this answer helpful, you can mark it as accepted or upvote it.